# ListPlot3D with specific coordinate points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have 2D values of a calculation the example dimension is 6x8 but normally I deal with dimensions 500s.I use ListPlot3D but I don't know how to impose the coordinates there without manipluating the 2D matrix and arrays and create something like {{x,y,value},{x,y,value}......}

```
fff = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
5.475791142740877`, -14.272825786774677`, 33.4382839562968`, 
64.29895513872745`, -68.0961640025078`, -84.55409049545428`, \
-200.43168128179911`}, {0, 108.2809132864027`, 96.33066430481864`, 
67.39038634897949`, -22.450932256751088`, -135.51651024533695`, \
-114.91838242492751`, 116.66288335614024`}, {0, 119.2795790153213`, 
65.8259686873095`, 142.50591927548047`, -110.7506031206303`, 
86.88430514579899`, -277.43024833209427`, -663.5701425108603`}, \
{0, 25.83813396477188`, 65.60966523505152`, -55.32158023192134`, 
17.625431413588235`, -218.01432554895248`, 163.51192536446618`, 
269.1632999426581`}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
ListPlot3D[fff, ImageSize -> Large, Mesh -> {50, 50}]
```

and lets assume that

```
x={0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.}; 
y={0., 0.07142857142857142, 0.14285714285714285, 0.21428571428571427, 
 0.2857142857142857, 0.3571428571428571, 0.42857142857142855, 0.5}
```

Is there something like PlotMagic[fff,x,y]? If not how can I create {{x1,y1,value11},{x1,y2,value12}......} efficiently?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is more elegant way to do it

```
pts = Join @@ 
  Table[{x[[i]], y[[j]], fff[[i, j]]}, {i, Length@x}, {j, Length@y}]
ListPointPlot3D[pts]
```

Comment: I apologize, did not see your answer

Comment: Thanks, really elegant and I can also use ListPlot3D because I would like a surface.

Answer (score 1):

```
fff = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    5.475791142740877`, -14.272825786774677`, 33.4382839562968`, 
    64.29895513872745`, -68.0961640025078`, -84.55409049545428`, \
-200.43168128179911`}, {0, 108.2809132864027`, 96.33066430481864`, 
    67.39038634897949`, -22.450932256751088`, -135.51651024533695`, \
-114.91838242492751`, 116.66288335614024`}, {0, 119.2795790153213`, 
    65.8259686873095`, 142.50591927548047`, -110.7506031206303`, 
    86.88430514579899`, -277.43024833209427`, -663.5701425108603`}, \
{0, 25.83813396477188`, 65.60966523505152`, -55.32158023192134`, 
    17.625431413588235`, -218.01432554895248`, 163.51192536446618`, 
    269.1632999426581`}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
x = {0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.};
y = {0., 0.07142857142857142, 0.14285714285714285, 
   0.21428571428571427, 0.2857142857142857, 0.3571428571428571, 
   0.42857142857142855, 0.5};
f = Table[{x[[i]], y[[j]], fff[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, Length[x]}, {j, 1, 
   Length[y]}];
ListPointPlot3D[f,, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "fff"}]
```

[image: fig1]